# Is there a method to bind varying numbers of rows inside a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, simplify

I have one large dataframe with 3 columns named `ID`, `x` and `y`. There are a few "ID"s which appear more than once (could be any number of times), and generally the "x" and "y" values are different except that "y" can be `NA` for more than one of the duplicate "ID"s. My goal is to get a dataframe in which every ID only appears once, but where the x and y values of the possible duplicates are additional new columns. Here is a simple example:

```
ID    x    y
 a    1    NA
 b    2    6
 a    3    7
 b    4    NA
 b    5    NA
```

This table should then become something in the form of:

```
ID    x1    y1    x2    y2    x3    y3
 a     1    NA     3     7    NA    NA
 b     2     6     4    NA     5    NA
```

The order of the additional columns does not matter so much as long as the pairs of x and y are still identifiable.

My biggest issue is that I need to apply this to a dataframe with thousands of different ID's and so far I could not find or write a function, which would perform this automatically.

So far, the closest thing to my goal I managed to get was using `unlist()`. E.g. looking at only the rows with `ID = "a"` and assigning them to a new dataframe A, I could use

```
unlist( append(distinct(A, ID), unlist(select(A, x, y))) )
```

But I could not apply this more generally to the whole dataframe.

I also looked at some ways of joining or merging the specific rows together, but I could not solve the problem of the varying numbers of required additional columns.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `data.table` `dcast` takes multiple `value.var`, it can be done with `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), ID ~ rowid(ID), value.var = c("x", "y"), sep="")
#  ID x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3
#1:  a  1  3 NA NA  7 NA
#2:  b  2  4  5  6 NA NA
```

---

In `tidyverse`, this can be done with `pivot_wider` (from the dev version of `tidyr`)

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(x, y))
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#   ID      x_1   x_2   x_3   y_1   y_2   y_3
#  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 a         1     3    NA    NA     7    NA 
#2 b         2     4     5     6    NA    NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "b"), x = 1:5, y = c(NA, 
6L, 7L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is reshaping your data. You need a `time` variable. We can use ave function with sequence along the rows. (I used x, you can use any non-factor variable or simply 1:nrow(df)). Then we reshape to wide

In base R you could do:

```
  reshape(transform(df,time=ave(x,ID,FUN=seq_along)),idvar = "ID",dir="wide",sep="")
  ID x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3
1  a  1 NA  3  7 NA NA
2  b  2  6  4 NA  5 NA
```